# pyodbc slow on execute many

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am \insertingdata into a microsoft sql server using pyodbc.
I am finding it is taking an incredible amount of time with even as little at a couple thousand rows (I honestly . I would really appreciate any faster solutions.

[Connector code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxWBJ.png)

[executemany code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6jSZ.png)

Comment: Avoid posting images of your code, just write it

Comment: Are you able to verify how long such operation would take when run directly from mssql console? Maybe that's not because of pyodbc, but maybe there is something wrong with sql structure (too many indexes for example)?

Comment: And yes, it would be easier to say anything more if you had post with actual code, not images. And with the whole code, not only a cut part of it.